# GetElementById not working. Maybe convert UTF-16?

Tags: c#, utf-8, utf-16

Hi guys I have the following issue with my code, which should log me automatically onto a website https://app.xyz.com/LoginEntry.aspx :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace loggy
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void loggy_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {



            try
            {

                HtmlDocument doc = loggy.Document;
                HtmlDocument username = doc.GetElementById("wtLayoutLogin_SilkUIFramework_wt8_block_wtUsername_wtUsername_wtUsernameInput");
                HtmlDocument password = doc.GetElementById("wtLayoutLogin_SilkUIFramework_wt8_block_wtPassword_wtPassword_wtPasswordInput");
                HtmlDocument submit = doc.GetElementById("wtLayoutLogin_SilkUIFramework_wt8_block_wtAction_wtAction_wtLoginButton");

                username.SetAttribute("value", "jon.doe@gmail.com");
                password.SetAttribute("value", "123");
                submit.InvokeMember("click");
            }

                catch
            {

            }


        }
    }
    }
```

Inspecting the login field shows me the following:

```
<input name="wtLayoutLogin$SilkUIFramework_wt8$block$wtUsername$wtUsername$wtUserNameInput" type="text" maxlength="250" size="28" id="wtLayoutLogin_SilkUIFramework_wt8_block_wtUsername_wtUsername_wtUserNameInput" tabindex="2" class="Mandatory" placeholder="Email or Username" onkeydown="return OsEnterKey('wtLayoutLogin_SilkUIFramework_wt8_block_wtAction_wtAction_wtLoginButton', arguments[0] || window.event)" autofocus="autofocus">
```

I cannot use the "GetElementById". I'm not very experienced in C# and I'm not sure how to convert the text so it is usable.

Could someone help me out, please?

Comment: How about providing some example HTML that demonstrates the issue, so we can help you instead of tossing out random uninformed speculation? People with questions often share assumptions or suppositions about what's really causing their problem, but as you'd expect from people who haven't *solved* their problems, the assumptions they come here with are not very often correct. My favorite problem solving heuristic: Write down the things you know with perfect certainty aren't the problem. It's usually one of those.

Comment: Hi Ed, I'm sorry, you are right. I have edited the post now. I hope it is better this way now?

Comment: Is this System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument rather than the AgilityPack HtmlDocument? Where are you getting it from? How are you loading the page? WebBrowser control?

Comment: I put in the entire code now. It is a System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument. I used a Windows Forms App and WebBrowser control to load the page.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I should have asked you exactly what you meant by *"I cannot use the "GetElementById""* before looking any further. Let this be a lesson to me.

The problem is that `HtmlDocument.GetElementById()` returns `HtmlElement`, not `HtmlDocument`. Your code won't compile because you're trying to make an assignment that's not possible (nor desirable, for that matter).

This will work:

```
var username = doc.GetElementById("wtLayoutLogin_SilkUIFramework_wt8_block_wtUsername_wtUsername_wtUsernameInput");
var password = doc.GetElementById("wtLayoutLogin_SilkUIFramework_wt8_block_wtPassword_wtPassword_wtPasswordInput");
var submit = doc.GetElementById("wtLayoutLogin_SilkUIFramework_wt8_block_wtAction_wtAction_wtLoginButton");
```

Or

```
HtmlElement username = doc.GetElementById("wtLayoutLogin_SilkUIFramework_wt8_block_wtUsername_wtUsername_wtUsernameInput");
HtmlElement password = doc.GetElementById("wtLayoutLogin_SilkUIFramework_wt8_block_wtPassword_wtPassword_wtPasswordInput");
HtmlElement submit = doc.GetElementById("wtLayoutLogin_SilkUIFramework_wt8_block_wtAction_wtAction_wtLoginButton");
```

All `var` does is define the variable as whatever type you're trying to assign to it. HtmlDocument.GetElementById()`is declared as returning`HtmlElement`, so if you hover the mouse over`var`in those lines, it'll tell you that`HtmlElement`is the actual type of`username` or whatever.

And jon.doe@gmail.com can now assume the Sun Warrior pose.

Comment: Thank you so much for that! And sorry again for the vague post in the beginning!